# How to dynamically listen for changes in field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have several similar fields in my form:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Ops[1][WorkCentre]">..</select>
<select class="form-control" name="Ops[2][WorkCentre]">..</select>
...
<select class="form-control" name="Ops[n][WorkCentre]">..</select>
```

I don't know how many such fields there will be, as the user adds the fields dynamically.

I need some way of executing a java script function when any of these inputs changes, and inside that function I need to be able to access the key of the input which has changed with regards to the 'Ops' array.

Im happy to use jquery. I was thinking something like

```
$('select[name=Ops[i][WorkCentre]').change(function(i){
    // A function using i
});
```

Or maybe a Javascript event listener?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event delegation:

```
// Listen for 'change' event on every element that has class 'form-control'
$(document).on('change', 'select.form-control', function() {
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
   // You code here ...
});
```

**UPDATE**

In order to extract the number from name attribute, you can set the name as follows:

```
name="Ops_[1]_[WorkCentre]"
```

and then split by '_':

```
var number = $(this).attr('name').split('_')[1];
```

**UPADATE #2**

A better solution would be to set the number in a separate attribute like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Ops[1][WorkCentre]" data-number="1">..</select>
```

and then retrieve it like this:

```
var number = $(this).attr('data-number');
```

Comment: Better to use `'select.form-control'`

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can then extract the 'number' from 'var name' ?

Comment: yes, the first wouldn't work because i need to submit an array, don't know why I didn't think of the second. Thanks